# How do I sum different currencies in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet where some columns are formatted in EUR, and some in USD. I would like to be able to sum them by taking into consideration the exchange rate. Example:

A1 = $10, A2 = €10

A3 = A1 + A2 ==> $10 + $(10*1.24) = $22.4

So basically, can I use SUMIF() on a cell formatting condition, or do I manually need to have a flag that specifies the currency for each column?

Comment: You'll need a flag. The `$` and euro signs are just cell formatting information. you can write a long condition to sum cells according to the currency flag.

Comment: If you find your question to be answered properly, please flag as such.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you set the B-column to be the exchange rate, you can use the sumproduct formula like this, with the following data set:

A1=$10, A2=€10, B1=1.24, B2=1

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A2;B1:B2)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Key off the Currency Symbol

The currency symbol, `€` or `$` in your values, is the first character therefore you can return it using the [LEFT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079?hl=en) function :

```
# A1=$20.45         # A2=€20.45  
    
  =LEFT(A1)           =LEFT(A2)
  =LEFT("$20.45")     =LEFT("€20.45")  
  ="$"                ="€"
```

[LEFT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079?hl=en) along with [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294?hl=en) can be used to return the sum of all the values in a range of values, while coverting the currency where necessary.

For example, if your range of currency values is in **A1:A2**  and `1.11` is the **EUR:USD** conversion rate :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A2, IF(LEFT(A1:A2)="$", 1, 1.11))
# or
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A2, IF(LEFT(A1:A2)="€", 1.11, 1))
```

Instead of hardcoding the exchange rate `1.11` , it can be a cell reference or a named range.

For example, where **B1** holds the exchange rate :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A2, IF(LEFT(A1:A2)="€", B1, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

> can I use SUMIF() on a cell formatting condition, or do I manually need to have a flag that specifies the currency for each column?

SUMIF, like all other worksheet functions (other than, to a limited extent, [CELL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267071)) cannot access the applied format.

So either GAS or you do indeed *manually need to have a flag that specifies the currency for each column*.